# How to call a function inside ternary operator in map function in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to call a ternary operator inside my map function in React but I am getting error

> Unexpected token, expected "..."

```
 <List>
      {[ 'My Profile','Explore More', 'Logout'].map((text, index) => {
        return (<ListItem button key={text}

        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            {index  === 0 && <PersonIcon /> }
            {index  === 1 && <ExploreIcon /> }
            {index  === 2 && <ExitToAppOutlinedIcon /> }
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={text} 
            {index === 2 && (onClick={logout})}
          />
        </ListItem>)
      })}
    </List>
```

above is the code that I tried please help me.

Comment: The code you posted has no ternary operator in it

Comment: There is no ternary/conditional operator in the code shared here. I would suggest just using a plain `if/else` or `switch` structure.

Comment: A ternary operator is an expression with a question mark and a colon, something like: `isEven(x) ? 'even' : 'odd'`. I don't see any of those in your snippet.

Comment: {index === 2 && (onClick={logout})}
is my ternary in 11th line of my code :)

Comment: @TKharaishvili its a ternary for if not condition...isnt it called ternary too?

Comment: [Ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary) (from Latin ternarius) is an adjective meaning "composed of three items".

Comment: i just wanna call a function logout if index is 2 whats the good way to do that here ?

Comment: Use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this notation:

```
<List>
  {[ 'My Profile','Explore More', 'Logout'].map((text, index) => {
    return (
        <ListItem button key={text}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            {index  === 0 && <PersonIcon /> }
            {index  === 1 && <ExploreIcon /> }
            {index  === 2 && <ExitToAppOutlinedIcon /> }
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText 
            onClick={index === 2? logout: undefined}
            primary={text} 
          />
      </ListItem>
    )
  })}
</List>
```

Comment: it worked thank you sooo much you save me :)

Comment: My pleasure, I'll appreciate you to select my answer

Comment: i tried but it says i have low reputation to do so